# Elasticsearch query 2.7M docs, 60 ms. Is it ok or it can be faster?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with 2.7M docs. There is my query:

```
GET ad_index/ad_type/_search
{
  "size": 20,
  "sort": {
    "until": "desc"
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "state": 2
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "until": {
              "gte": "now"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    } 
  },
  "aggs" : {
    "categories": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "category_id",
        "size": 2000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query doesn't have match subquery.
I have 1 node with 1 shard and 0 replicas.

Query time - 60 ms. Without aggregation - 40 ms.
Hits ~ 50000.

Is it okay or it could be faster? I want 10 ms. I get <10ms with MySQL.

I use ES 2.4. Index size 1.34 GB. I'm not interested in score.

UPD.

My mapping:

```
{
  "ad_index": {
    "mappings": {
      "ad_type": {
        "properties": {
          "customer_id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "deleted": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "dynamic_fields": {
            "properties": {
              "-icq-3": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "phone-3": {
                "type": "string"
              }
              "email-3": {
                "type": "string"
              }

              //and 100 more sparse dynamic fields 

          },
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "category_id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "until": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
          },
          "state": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "text": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Other queries:

```
GET ad_index/ad_type/_search
{
  "size": 20,
  "sort": {
    "until": "desc"
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "state": 2
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "until": {
              "gte": "now"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "category_id" : [1029, 121, ... here can be more than 200 values]
          }
        }
      ]
    } 
  },
  "aggs" : {
    "categories": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "category_id",
        "size": 2000
      }
    }
  }
}

GET ad_index/ad_type/_search
{
  "size": 20,
  "sort": {
    "until": "desc"
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
        "match": {
            "_all": "some text"
          }
        }
      ], 
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "state": 2
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "until": {
              "gte": "now"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "category_id" : [1029, 121, ... here can be more than 200 values]
          }
        }
      ]
    } 
  },
  "aggs" : {
    "categories": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "category_id",
        "size": 2000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you comparing MySQL to ElasticSearch??? x_x

Comment: it is ok and yes it should be faster. i use to get 40 ms with big es query with more than 10 filters on 150 million documents. Can you paste schema of the documents. Also your query can be tuned more.Since you are just filtering the documents. if you are not interested in score you can move your filters inside filtered filters with boolean filters and enable _cache on filters(except on range as range filters are not suitable for _cache if your value for changes more often). share mappings/schema and other use case queries

Comment: posted some additional info in the UPD section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bit slow, because you are using simple query.

1. Try to experiment with shards for this amount of documents try 3-5 shards.
2. Make sure that you allow right amount of memory By Setting ES_HEAP_SIZE (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html)
3. Profile your query to see what is going on https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-profile.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do I have an alternative to simple queries?

Comment: @AntonyZh By simple query i mean that you are not using text analysis you have query which is very easy to do filtering by so you query is good, i assume problem is with setup

Comment: I increased number of shards up to 3, increased heap size up to 4 GB and installed ElasticSearch 5.0 GA. Now i have 30 ms instead of 60 on the same queries. Thanks!